# Contracts in Let language

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket, let

I saw a question which asked about a contract of a method in a pet language known as let.The language is not important but does contract means that 
things that the method takes as an argument and its  value after evaluating?

```
(define extend-env*
  (lambda (syms vals old-env)
    (if (null? syms)
      old-env
      (extended-env-record 
        (car syms) 
        (car vals)
        (extend-env* (cdr syms)
                     (cdr vals) 
                     old-env)))))
```

So in here the method takes a symbol a value and an environment and I think it produces a new environment.
Does that mean contract for this method is Identifier(Variable),Value,Environment = Environment ?

Comment: Indeed, that is what I would understand. Your contract with the method is that you promise to deliver it some arguments of a certain type, and that it will give you back a result of a certain type.

Answer (score 1):

Your functions starts like this:

```
(lambda (syms vals old-env) ...)
```

Here `sym` stand for symbol and thus `syms` stands for `a list of syms` aka `a list of symbols`. In the same manner `vals` stands for `a list of values`. Finally `old-env` is an environment.

This covers the input to the function. To confirm that `syms` is supposed to be a list of symbols, look at how `syms` is used in the body. We see thee uses: `(null? syms)`, `(car syms)`, and, `(cdr syms)`. This means we guess correctly.

To see type of the output, look for the expression(s) that produce return values.
The simplest is `old-env` which is an environment. If the function always returns the same type of value, we have determined that the output is an environment. It best to check that the other return expressions also return environments though.

To sum up: the contract seen from Racket is:

```
extend-env* : list-of-symbols list-of-values environment -> environment
```

Now in your program the symbols represent identifiers, so you could also write:

```
extend-env* : list-of-identifiers list-of-values environment -> environment
```

if you document that identifiers are represented as symbols.

Comment: This seems correct.I know symbols are also lists but I dont know if we should write lists-of-symbols in a contract or just symbol since it expresses a certain type.

Comment: A symbol is not a list. A list of symbols is a list. A contract is a description of the input and output types. As a contract in a comment the above description is fine. If you need contracts in a specific context, you need to elaborate on where you need them.